# Making a connection to api(OAuth2.0) with php and storing the info local

Tags: php, mysql, oauth

Dear fellow programmers.

My school has it's own api, sowing classes, teachers etc (sjon result).
What I want to do is create a school app so all the students can see where they have class on their mobile.

What is want is:
**Make a connection to the api via oauth 2.0 with php.
Store the values in a local MySQL database
(later stadium)Connect the database to the app and show the results in a table**

For now it's just local later on it will work with a SQL server.

I have been trying for three days but I just can't get it to work.

Our school gave me a KEY and a SECREY_KEY

I see alot of info about PECL files and I have never worked with this.

I want to use both keys to get the tokens, the api will eventually give me a mobile login page to login and get my personal student results

*How am I supposed to do this, is there a template which makes me fill in my keys and connect to the api?*

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Tried this repo, but cant figure it out https://code.google.com/p/oauth2-php/

Tried to put PECL files in my php, didnt work either.